# Y-Axis values not showing in facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I'm completing an assignment for a class (non-coding related, just making graphs), and I'm trying to make `facet_wrap` of surface temperature against shade type, factored by surface type. However, y-values for temperature are not showing.

Here's what the graph looks like
[image]

The `axis.text.x=element_blank()` are just for the x-axis and y values are absent regardless.

Here's my code:

```
graph2 <- ggplot(df, aes(surface,surf_temp,fill=as.factor(surface)))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(~shade,scales='free_y') +
  labs(title="Surface Temperature Distribution by Shade Type and Surface Type", 
       x="Surface Type",
       y="Surface Temperature (°C)") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=8)) +
  guides(color=guide_legend("Surface Type")) +
  scale_y_discrete(labels=yaxislabels2)
```

Comment: It's unusual to see "surface temperature" mapped as a discrete value, perhaps this was unintended? I'm guessing `surf_temp` is character or factor data where you probably want a numeric value that would use `scale_y_continuous` instead of `scale_y_discrete`.

Comment: What is yaxialabels2?

Answer (score 0):

As you've used `scales='free_y'` within `facet_wrap`, different axis values will be used for each facet, e.g. if cloudy varied from 10-12 deg and full sun from 13-16 deg, their respective y axes will only display these values (good for comparison within facets but not between). If you have certain y limits that you want to be shared across the facets (e.g. from 10-16) - so you can see comparisons amongst groups - use `scales = "fixed"`. Otherwise, make sure `yaxislabels2` covers the full range of all groups.